# Why won't LED light?

Tags: pcb, circuit-analysis, fault

So I'm attempting to diagnose what's wrong with my daughters light up fidget spinner after she dropped it on the floor (and if possible fix). But I seem to be having a failing at electronics 101 and am trying to work out what I'm missing!

The PCB looks incredibly simple, 3 batteries in series, an LED and 2 components that sound like switches with a ball bearing inside - which would make sense, activating the LED when they spin. I've put together what I think the circuit looks like where SW1 and SW2 are those rotary switches. I've put a schematic for how I think it works, and a photo of the PCB below.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fup9v4.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

[image]

[image]

I've tried checking a couple of things with a multi-meter. Using a connection test, that actually pushes enough power through the LED to confirm that it lights up OK. Using a volt-meter between `A-B` I read 0V and between `A-C` I read 3.1V.

What really starts to baffle me though, is that I've tried shorting the two connections at point C, using my multi-meter probe (and tried a screwdriver) neither of which light the LED - which I don't understand?

Comment: Led could have a microcontroller in it. The second picture seems to show that. The switches may not connect like you think. Or the led is dead.

Comment: @Passerby good point, the LED does cycle colours and which would indeed need something like that. The LED does work using the power from my multi-meter in "circuit test" mode - where it beeps if it's got a connection.

Comment: @Passerby I'll add I'm new to this exchange network. Let me know if this is a bad fit/unanswerable and I'll take it down :) But I felt like there was some basic learning that I'm missing in here somewhere.

Comment: Frankly the only other thing that could be happening is a bad solder joint or battery contact. Based on the pictures, shorting A to C should trigger it. Maybe the batteries are dead or reversed

Comment: 3.1V is low for 3 batteries, usually at the just-about empty end if they are in normal condition. It may well be the LED needs 3.2V to 3.3V to work if it's an auto-colour change LED. Either the batteries happen to be low at the same time, or what could have happened is that one got damaged. A violent impact in the right direction can cause drastic decreases in capacity. Try three fresh batteries before you try anything else.

Comment: you measure 3.1V at A-C because one or both switches are open

Comment: @jsotola yeah that's what I concluded. 0V between `A-B` indicated to me that the first switch is closed, which is why I thought shorting the switch at `C` would light the LED, but it didn't.

Comment: that conclusion is incorrect ... if both switches are open then the voltage across each one will be zero

Comment: short A-C and measure voltage across the LED terminals  .... also, what is printed on the cells?? .... also, wiggle the LED, maybe it is detached at one terminal

Comment: Crack in the PCB track or solder termination of one of the battery terminals or switches? Use the continuity test on your multimeter and go around the circuit until you have found it.

Comment: @winny that was a good approach. I took out the batteries and tested everything, including the switches and determined that the switch across A-B wasn't working regardless of it's orientation (but the same was not true for the switch at C). So I soldered across the joint and fixed. If you add your suggestion on diagnosing as an answer I'll accept.